# How to Whitelist Instant Payment Notification (IPN)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, paypal, paypal-ipn

Our site should handle Instant Payment Notification (IPN) .

We should permit accesses only from Paypal to our site for security reason. (i.e. we should block HTTP POST requests from other network locations.)

Paypal publishes IP address list of their servers.
However, Paypal recommends to use the result of DNS results because they can change IP address of server often and they won't make any report in advance[1].

> PayPal changes its records often and does not provide advance notification of changes

To achieve the above requirements, we have to integrate a system that automatically detects the change of IP address of a certain domain name (like ipnpb.paypal.com), and update the firewall setting of our server.

(To be specific, our site is integrated on AWS, and we use security group setting other than firewall setting.)

But do we really have to do this?
Does anyone know more sophisticated solution of this problem?

[1] https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1056
[2] https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1006&pmv=print&impressions=false&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

> We should permit accesses only from Paypal to our site for security
>   reason. (i.e. we should block HTTP POST requests from other network
>   locations.)

I do not think there is a security risk from having your IPN listener open to the public. I am certain this is the common setup.

As you noted, PayPal itself does not provide a timely list of its current IPN services.  This makes it impossible to have an accurate list of source IP ranges in your security groups.

Also, the nature of the IPN validation request makes it an unlikely attack vector.  You need to post back the request to a known PayPal URL (ipn.paypal.com), where they validate the token and data.

If they do not verify the request, then ignore the request.  This factor means PayPal would reject any request that did not originate from them in the first place.

We have left all our IPN listeners open to the public for years without any incident or attack. We follow all resonanable security policies, and run a PCI compliant payment platform, with monthly PCI vulnerability scanning.

If your system is well secured in every other respect, leaving the IPN listener open to the public is a negligible security risk.